# how to export only selected files in mysql to a .csv

Tags: mysql, sql

how to export only selected files in mysql to a .csv files

example:

```
Select * from tablename where column name = $somevalue
```

how to export the returned value from that query?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: sorry i dont even know where to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `into outfile` (documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html)):

```
select *
into outfile 'the/file/you/want.csv'
from tablename
where column = $somevalue
```

Oh, to add column names you need to use `union all`.  Yuch, because this may require that you cast certain columns explicitly to the right format.

```
select <all columns except "isheader">
into outfile 'the/file/you/want.csv'
from ((select 1 as isheader, <list of column names in quotes>
      ) union all
      (select 0 as isheader, t.*
       from tablename
       where column = $somevalue
      )
     ) t
order by isheader desc
```

For instance, if you have one column called `id`:

```
select id
into outfile 'the/file/you/want.csv'
from ((select 1 as isheader, 'id' as id
      ) union all
      (select 0 as isheader, t.id
       from tablename t
       where column = $somevalue
      )
     ) t
order by isheader desc
```

Comment: shall i write this code in phpmyadmin?

Comment: mate how to put header or title in the column? i managed to put delititers already

Comment: @BelmarkCaday . . . If you click on the "here" link (or go to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html), you'll have the full documentation for the syntax.  There are several options you might be interested in.

Comment: cmon man. i already spent 2 hours  trying to figure out how to add column names.. it doesnt say there in your link how.

Comment: @BelmarkCaday . . . Duh, I forgot the `into outfile` doesn't do column names.  You need to put them in using a `union all` query.  You can try just `select <column names in quotes> union all <your query here>`, but the ordering is not guaranteed.  The form in the solution is guaranteed to put the headers first.